# Does ruby have the array method select! or not?

Tags: ruby

```
> a = %w(a b c)
 => ["a", "b", "c"] 
> a.select!{|e| !e.nil?}
NoMethodError: undefined method `select!' for ["a", "b", "c"]:Array
    from (irb):2

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-darwin10.5.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02
```

The doc says there is a method called select! in array.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000252

Comment: as below it's not in 1.8.7, but you could use delete_if / reject! with inverse logic (or even implement select! yourself by reopening the array class)

Comment: By the way, there's a new version of REE out, 2011.03, that includes several important bug and security fixes.

Answer (score 12):

Ruby 1.8.7 *does* have `Array#reject!`, though:

```
>> a = [1, 2, nil]
=> [1, 2, nil]
>> a.reject! &:nil?
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer if @Nadal's original question is really "how do I get this to work". I also think it's important to clarify the different locations to get documentation for the various versions of Ruby that are now "floating" around its ecosystem.

Answer (score 7):

The docs you linked to are for Ruby 1.9.2. [Ruby 1.8.7 Arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html) don't have `select!`.

EDIT: As a future reference, you can view [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/#api) for the different versions of Ruby that are out there.

Answer (score 3):

`Array#select!` was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2.

To get it in older Ruby versions and stop worrying about which versions of Ruby have which methods, you can [`require "backports/1.9.2/array/select"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports).

You can also use `Array#reject!` or combine `#replace` and `#select` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The code works for me, but I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 (which is the same version of the document you linked).

Here is the [1.8.7 documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000331). Notice only `select` is available, not `select!`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using Ruby 1.8.7 . The docs you refer to are for Ruby 1.9.2 . 1.8.7 does not include `Array#select!`, as you can see here:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/